# Password mismatch in registration form that inherits from UserCreationForm

Tags: python, django

I have a form that inherits from the `UserCreationForm`. The file looks like this:

```js
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import password_validation
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group

from main.models.users import MyUser


class MyUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    group = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ("group", "email", "username", "email", "password1", "password2")

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(MyUserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

For some reason, when trying to fill up the form, I get a password mismatch error like so:

`ERROR - {'password_mismatch': "The two password fields didn't match."}`

I tried overriding the clean_password1 and clean_password2 with no help. Code:

```
def clean_password1(self):
    password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
    try:
        password_validation.validate_password(password1, self.instance)
    except forms.ValidationError as error:

        # Method inherited from BaseForm
        self.add_error('password1', error)
    return password1
```

Any ideas why this is happening? Why is it thinking that both of my passwords are not identical? I'm sure they are, as I tried a million times and even copy and pasted.

view:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyUserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print(f"Valid form. Choosen group: {form.cleaned_data.get('group')}")
            user = form.save()
            group = Group.objects.get(name=form.cleaned_data.get('group'))
            user.groups.add(group)
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, f"Thanks, {form.cleaned_data.get('username')}, "
            f"for signing up as a {form.cleaned_data.get('group')} ")
            return redirect('main:homepage')
        else:
            logger.error(form.error_messages)
            for msg in form.error_messages:
                messages.error(request, f'{msg}: {form.error_messages[msg]}')
            return render(request,
                          template_name='main/register.html',
                          context={'form': form})
    else:
        form = MyUserCreationForm()
        return render(request,
                      template_name='main/register.html',
                      context={'form': form})
```

Answer (score -1):

i am not sure about code but you can try this

```
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
      #inhereting Usercreation form
      form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
          form.save()

          #validating the password match while creating the user.
          username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
          raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
          user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
          login(request, user)
          return redirect('home')
   else:
     form = UserCreationForm()
  return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: I suppose an indentation error in `signup`, is it so? Can you add explanation for you code - what changed and why?

Comment: yes there was an indention error and there isn't much change i m observing apart from user of password2, But i m sure that this logic view will do for you. :)

Comment: Code is for computers, text is for humans ;) Both parts are needed for good answer. I mean to add explanations into text of your answer

Comment: you might have inherited PandaUserCreationForm instead of PmyUserCreationForm

Comment: You mistake me with OP ;)

Comment: the problem is that the form turns out invalid all the time.  meaning that if statement is not met.The error is the password_mismatch even when the passwords are identicle (@VIVEKVIKASH - the Panda was a misspell when copying it here)